# TextUtils.join on integer ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have 3 booleans which indicate if an int should be added to a list or not, then I would like to use `TextUtils.join()` on this list.

How should I proceed ?

```
ArrayList<Integer> types = new ArrayList<Integer>();

if (m_bWithA) {
   types.add(this.TYPE_A); //TYPE_A is an int
}
if (m_bWithB) {
   types.add(this.TYPE_B); 
}
if (m_bWithC) {
   types.add(this.TYPE_C); 
}

TextUtils.join("|", types);
```

But it says that we can only use `TextUtils.join()` on `Object[]`.

Should I use another function or a different type of object ?

Comment: Isn't  Integer `ArrayList` an `Iteratable`, which is accepted by `.join` [here](http://tinyurl.com/ppmvlpc)

Comment: Agreed with Sourabh, .join will work with any Iterable. If you look in the docs, Iterable extends CharSequence, CharSequence extends I believe most primitive types. I have used .join to join an ArrayList of Integers many times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `TextUtils.join(types.toArray())`